# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to validate the fields but it only shows errors. My index.html and js are in the same page. even I have tried with the different versions of angular-route.min.js and also angular.js but I get always the same error.
         
        
        
            AngularJs | Basic Login Form

```
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-view></div>  

    <script>    
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", [ " ngRoute " ]);
    myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
                })
        .when('/dashboard',{
            resolve:{
                "check": function($location){
                    if(!rootScope.loggedIn){
                        $location.path('/');
                    }
                }
            },
            templateUrl:'dashboard.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'

        });
    });

    myApp.controller('LoginCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.submit = function(){     
            if($scope.username =='admin' && $scope.password =='admin'){
                $rootScope.uname = $scope.username; //$rootScope
            $rootScope.password $scope.password;
                    $location.path('/dashboard');

            }
        };
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There shouldn't be spaces in the string in your module definition. `"ngRoute"` and `" ngRoute "` are not equal, and the latter won't be recognized as the ngRoute module.

Comment: which js files have you added? did you add angularjs and angular-route.js ?

Comment: i tried " ngRoute "  also but neither of the routes are working..even after removing angular.js  file it didnt worked so i let it be in the code..

Answer (score 0):

you are forget "=" on $rootScope.password

```
myApp.controller('LoginCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.submit = function(){     
        if($scope.username =='admin' && $scope.password =='admin'){
            $rootScope.uname = $scope.username; //$rootScope
        $rootScope.password = $scope.password;  // here
                $location.path('/dashboard');

        }
    };
```